# How to Push to Shared BitBucket Repository

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Here My Problem is I Have a Git Repository and I Shared that repository to another user by sending invitation and allowed as admin.

I am doing the push,pull with my SSH keys so what I need to know is:

1.The other person unable push to this repository [I sent my Repo public key to him that exists in my system]
2.The other person is unable to pull as well

I have googled it but it's still confusing. Could anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The other user needs to sign up at Bitbucket, and set up his own profile with its own SSH key pair.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, He also have the own BitBucket Id and if he register with his own key pair how his commits redirected to my repo(I created a repo and shared to him).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends on the right you gave him, there are *`admin`*, *`read/write`*, and *`read only`* rights to repos. So *`admin`* can even *delete* the repo, and *assign* the rights, *`read/write`* access allows others to do *pull/push* operation consequently, and *`read only`* access allows the only *pull* operations. To close even access to the repo, just remove the user from collaborations.

You have only to put your SSH-key to your bitbucket's profile, using the **Manage Account/SSH Keys** menu. And don't give it to other man, even public part.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I gave the admin rights to him here my main doubt is can I need to send my SSH public key to him that what I have in System or They need to commit to this repo with his own SSH.

Comment: @RamBen you have to only put your ssh key to your bitbucket's profile, not giving it to other man.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am new to this GIt n BitBucket,
can you explain how he can push his commits to my repository. If you are confused with my details let me explain again 
I have Bitbucket account with named REPO1 and doing commit from my system with my SSH key now according to my office instructions another guy (B) need to work on the same REPO1 so I invited him to join this REPO1 and gave admin access.
1. He tried with his own SSH key it saying while push  "! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)"
2.Then I gave my SSH public key no use 
So I can you explain how to do this.

Comment: @RamBen you shell allow him an write access to your repo, in the repo settings. I mean read/write of course. And he also shell to add his key into his account, to make pushes into the bitbucket.

Comment: Thanks Малъ Скрылевъ It solved Thanks for the patient support.